# SOQL Error in Compare Date

Tags: soql, date, comparable

Could you please help me for fix my SOQL Query?

I have SOQL Scrip like :

```
    SELECT Employee_No__c FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c  
WHERE Payroll_Name__c=:selectedPayrollName 
AND Payroll_Name__c != null  
AND  Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c < Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c 
GROUP BY Employee_No__c
```

But I get Error :

> expecting a colon, found 'Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c' 
>   and In Query Editor I get error : 
>   Unknown error parsing query

And when I try to change `AND  Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c < Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c`  with `Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c != null`

I Get the result..

So how to compare date in SOQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really compare two fields in SOQL. Instead you can achieve the desired result in the following way:

```
for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c objHREMPASSIGNMENT : [SELECT Employee_No__c,
                                                  Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c
                                                  Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c
                                             FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c  
                                             WHERE Payroll_Name__c=:selectedPayrollName 
                                              AND Payroll_Name__c != null 
                                          GROUP BY Employee_No__c ]) {

if(objHREMPASSIGNMENT.Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c < objHREMPASSIGNMENT.Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c )
    lstHREMPASSIGNMENT.add(objHREMPASSIGNMENT);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The issue you have got here is not just about comparing date fields, it is more about comparing two fields of the same record. Please refer to this post: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093VkIAI

Simply put, queries like below:

```
Select Id, Name From CustomObject__c Where A_Field__c < B_Field__c
```

Simply won't work in SOQL.

If you don't hit the governor limit, you can try to following:

```
List<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c > QResults = new List<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c  >();
for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c h: [SELECT id,Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c,Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c LIMIT 30000]){
   if(h.Employee_No__r.Terminate_Date__c < h.Employee_No__r.Pay_Thru_Date__c){
      QResults.add(h);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom formula field to compare those two fields and put it under your custom object.

Comment: +1 for formula field. Probably the easiest, safest and fastest solution for this case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter a field against another field. Take a look at the documentation for [*fieldExpression*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm) (emphasis mine):

> The field expression syntax of the WHERE clause in a SOQL query consists of a field name, a comparison operator, and a value that’s used to compare with the value in the field name.
>
> *fieldExpression* uses the following syntax:
>
> ```
> fieldName comparisonOperator value
> ```
>
> *fieldName*
> The name of a field in the specified object. Use of single or double quotes around the name will result in an error. You must have at least read-level permissions to the field. It can be any field except a long text area field, encrypted data field, or base64-encoded field. It does not need to be a field in the fieldList.
>
> *comparisonOperator*
> Case-insensitive operators that compare values.
>
> *value*
> A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. **You must supply a native value—other field names or calculations are not permitted.** If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use salesforce Date functions. In a SOQL query you can specify either a particular date or a date literal. A date literal is a fixed expression that represents a relative range of time, such as last month, this week, or next year. For example

- LAST_N_DAYS:n    For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the
  current day and continues for the past n days.   SELECT Id FROM Account
  WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365
- NEXT_N_DAYS:n    For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the
  current day and continues for the next n days.   SELECT Id FROM
  Opportunity WHERE CloseDate > NEXT_N_DAYS:15